# Read json file in React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm trying to read a json file in my path and store its content in a useState variable
I tried a lot and searched for solutions but did not find anything

mydata.json:

```
{
        "key":"value"
}
```

my code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View,Button,Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import RNFS  from "react-native-fs";

function App({route}){
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState({});
  try {
    RNFS.readFile("mydata.json","utf-8", function(err,data){
      const jsonDataObject = JSON.parse(data.toString());
      setJsonData(jsonDataObject);
  });
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.content}>
      <Text>
        hello 
      </Text>
      <Button onPress={()=>(console.log("your json : ",jsonData))} title='print' />
    </View>
  );
}


styles = StyleSheet.create(
  {
    content:{
      flex:1,
      alignItems:"center",
      justifyContent:"center"
      
    }
  }
)
export default App;
```

It is supposed to read the file, put it in the jsonData variable, and then print the content when the button is pressed

When I press the button it shows me :

```
    LOG : {}
    LOG : {}
    LOG : {}
```

Expected result:

```
    LOG : {"key":"value"}
    LOG : {"key":"value"}
    LOG : {"key":"value"}
```

Please help me and thank you

Comment: *"It is supposed to read the file, put it in the jsonData variable, and then print the content when the button is pressed"*  --  Okay, so what **is** happening?  Errors in the console?  Does `mydata.json` actually exist where you think it does? IE not `/assets/mydata.json` etc ..  More debugging info is needed here ...

Comment: You currently are reading the file on every re-render. You should put the json reading parts in an [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) that will run only on the first render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things wrong with your code. If your readFile block of code actually managed to execute you would get stuck in an infinite set state loop. All non-hook code is called at every render. So as your code currently exist, you are setting state every time you read the file. Setting state causes a re-render; and you read the file every time there's a  re-render.

You dont actually get to see this happen because your callback is never actually being executed. [RNFS.readFile](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#readfilefilepath-string-encoding-string-promisestring) doesnt take a callback as an argument. It instead returns a promise. So your code should be something like this:

```js
    RNFS.readFile("mydata.json","utf-8")
     .then(fileContents=>{
       const jsonDataObject = JSON.parse(fileContents)
       setJsonData(jsonDataObject)
     })
     .catch(error=> {
        console.error(error);
      })
```

And then to avoid the set state loop you should wrap this code in an `useEffect` with an empty dependency array:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
 RNFS.readFile("mydata.json","utf-8")
     .then(fileContents=>{
       const jsonDataObject = JSON.parse(fileContents)
       setJsonData(jsonDataObject)
     })
     .catch(error=> {
        console.error(error);
      })
},[])
```

Comment: react native open failed : Enoent (No such file or directory)

Comment: Where exactly is the file on the device?

Comment: You could try doing ``${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/mydata.json``, but if the json isnt in the Document directory then that will fail, but you need to know in advance the path to the file

Comment: The file is located where the app.js is located

Comment: react native open failed : Enoent (No such file or directory) open 'data/user/0/com.myapp/files/mydata.json'

Comment: If its located in your app bundle then you dont need RNFS. You can just import it like any other js file

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/0l2K_sY2y

Comment: What if I want to write on it??

Comment: Keep the effect provided in the answer above. Choose a location to store the file on the device. Keep your jsonData state. Use an `useEffect` to subscribe to jsonData state changes and then write jsonData to file